# RF433 Rpi Serial cannot read signals in Python

Tags: pi-3b+, python-3

I am running this code.

```
import serial
import time

serialport = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0',baudrate=1200, timeout=3)


t = "ttt"
while True:
   serialport.flush()
   serialport.write(t.encode())
   rcv =serialport.read()

   print(rcv)
```

I have enabled Serial on `raspi-config`.

I have connected RF receiver `MX-RM-5V` to `Rx GPIO 15` and RF transmitter  `FS1000A` to `Tx GPIO 14` on a `Rpi3B`. Always the output of the received message is empty. I am also using `piscope` to monitor the outputs of the Pins. When I connect Rx and Tx Pins together, I can see the message correctly (bypassing the RFs). Receiver and Transmitter work perfectly because I can test them in a RpiPico that I own.

Is there something I miss?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using `/dev/serial0` rather than `/dev/ttys0`.

What response is the message "ttt" meant to elicit?  `readline` expects a new line character in the response.

Comment: tried also `/dev/serial0` with no change in output. Also, checked with `serialport.read()`

Comment: You need to edit that information into your question.  You also need to explain why you expect a response and what response you expect to `ttt`.  All relevant information needs to be added to your question.